# EntityManager (@PersistenceContext) always returns null on 'find'

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa, wildfly

I am getting started with JEE. I grabbed a new student IntelliJ IDEA license and created a new JEE project with Wildfly 10.0 as an AS.

Somewhere in my restful api classes:

```
import com.zarkopafilis.beans.Post;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/posts")
@Stateless
public class GetPost {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getPost(@PathParam("id") Integer id){

    Post post = em.find(Post.class ,  id , LockModeType.READ);

    if(post == null){
        return "No post found with id " + id;
    }

    return "Title: " + post.getTitle() + '\n' + "Content: " + post.getContent();
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getRoot(){
    return "root";
}
}
```

This 'Post' class looks like the following: (It's a orm-mapped bean with hibernate)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="uni_id")
private long uniId;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@Column(name="title")
private String title;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "content")
private String content;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "uni_name")
private String universityName;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "department_name")
private String departmentName;

@NotNull
@Min(0)
@Column(name = "upvotes")
private int upvotes;
```

....getters and setters....

I have manually created the table and some entries to use for testing. I have also properly configured datasources inside intellij as well as inside standalone.xml at wildfly. I always get a null post returned by em.find though.

Comment: Maybe you're not targetting the database/schema you thing you're targetting. Maybe You forgot to commit the test insertions you made.

Comment: @JBNizet The test insertions are there and created with MysqlWorkbench
The code "sees" the table because it notifies me that it exists (on startup when it tries to create it if it doesnt exist). I've also got jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testschema as a <jta-data-source> inside persistence.xml

Comment: @JB Nizet  (IDK if I tagged you properly)

Comment: Can you show your persistence.xml??

Comment: Maybe there are no data in it ? In persistence.xml, there is a setting for dropping and re-creating all tables on startup. Are you sure this one is not on ?